# Effective field theory of inflation in the slow roll case

Tags: cosmological-inflation, effective-field-theory

I'm reading [this set of notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/db275/TEACHING/STRINGS/EFT.pdf) by Daniel Baumann on the effective field theory of inflation but I can't quite understand one step in section 3.1.1 concerning slow roll inflation.

Basically, the author says the Lagrangian in this case is (eq 3.5):

$$
\mathcal L = M_{\text{Pl}}^2 \dot H g^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu U \partial_\nu U - M_{\text{Pl}}^2(3H^2+\dot H)
$$

where $U = t+\pi$.

However, in the decoupling limit, the $\pi$ field no longer couples to the metric fluctuations and only sees the unperturbed FRW metric. That is (eq 3.7):

$$
g^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu U \partial_\nu U \to -1-2\dot \pi +(\partial_\mu \pi)^2
$$

From this he concludes that the lagrangian for the $\pi$ field in this limit is (eq 3.8):

$$
\mathcal L_{\text{s.r.}} = M_{\text{Pl}}^2 \dot H (\partial_\mu \pi)^2
$$

I don't quite grasp this last step. I concede that the $M_{\text{Pl}}^2(3H^2+\dot H)$ from the original lagrangian doesn't affect the dynamics of $\pi$ and can be disconsidered; by the same principle, the $-1$ in $-1-2\dot \pi +(\partial_\mu \pi)^2$ also goes away. But what about the $-2\dot \pi$? It should add a $-2M_{\text{Pl}}^2 \dot H \dot \pi$ term to the $\pi$ lagrangian, which I don't see why it's thrown away (it's not a total derivative).

What is the extremely obvious thing I'm stupidly missing here?

Comment: Just a guess, but if you integrate that term by parts you get $M_p^2 \ddot{H} \pi$, maybe you can neglect this piece since $\ddot{H}$ should be suppressed in the slow roll limit.